# onBlur is not getting Called on <img />tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, blur

I am trying to call onBlur on the image page but it's not working. here is the code: 
it's a class component

```js
showToolTip = () => {
    console.log("called");
    this.setState({ copyMessage: "Copy To Clipboard" });
};

copyToClipboard = () => {
    this.copy_span.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    this.setState({ copyMessage: "Copied!" }, () => {
        this.copyRef.current.focus();
    });
};
```

```
<img
    ref={this.copyRef}
    data-tip
    data-for="clip"
    src={require('../../assets/img/copy.svg')}
    alt={''}
    className="copy_link_image"
    onBlur={this.showToolTip}
    onClick={this.copyToClipboard}
/>
<ReactTooltip
    id="clip"
    type="dark"
>
    <span>{this.state.copyMessage}</span>
</ReactTooltip>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `onBlur` is called once your element had focus and it loses it. Is it what you are trying to accomplish ? (cf . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)

Comment: i just wanted to change the copyMessage state when i click on the img tag to "copied" and when i click somewhere else, it should run onBlur and change the state back to default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contrary to popular belief you can use onBlur with an img tag:
https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#focus-events

> onFocus onBlur
>
> These focus events work on all elements in the React DOM, not just
> form elements.

add a new callback for onBlur called removeMessage

```
removeMessage = () => {
    this.setState({ copyMessage: "" })
}

showToolTip = () => {
    console.log("called");
    this.setState({ copyMessage: "Copy To Clipboard" });
};

copyToClipboard = () => {
    this.copy_span.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    this.setState({ copyMessage: "Copied!" }, () => {
      this.copyRef.current.focus();
    });
};
```

change the showToolTip to onMouseEnter and add new removeMessage callback for onBlur

```
<img 
    ref={this.copyRef} data-tip data-for="clip" src={require( "../../assets/img/copy.svg")} alt={ ""} className="copy_link_image" 
    tabindex = "0"
    onFocus={this.showToolTip}
    onBlur={this.removeMessage} 
    onMouseEnter={this.showToolTip}
    onMouseOut={this.removeMessage}
    onClick={this.copyToClipboard} 
/>
```

Comment: yeah , may be i can customize these,

Comment: hehe, yep you did answer with onBlur, but when i put onBlur it wasn't getting called, but i liked your idea of onmouseenter and onmouseout

Comment: oh yea , got it , i just need to put tabIndex="0" then only ```onBlur``` will work , it's working that way

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you are trying to do by adding and removing an event listener on the whole window after clicking on the image:

```js
const ReactTooltip = props => <div>{props.children}</div>

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    copyMessage: ""
  }

  copyRef = React.createRef()

  showToolTip = () => {
    console.log("Tooltip");
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.sortOfBlur);
  };

  sortOfBlur = (e) => {
    if (e.target !== this.copyRef.current) {
      this.showToolTip();
    }
  }

  copyToClipboard = () => {
    console.log('Copied!');
    window.addEventListener('click', this.sortOfBlur);
  };

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <img ref={this.copyRef} data-tip="data-tip" data-for="clip" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt={""} className="copy_link_image" onClick={this.copyToClipboard}/>
      <ReactTooltip id="clip" type="dark">
        <span>{this.state.copyMessage}</span>
      </ReactTooltip>
    </div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

onBlur event does not work on img tag, it works on input field only.
You can attach event handler on document click there you can change the state back to default.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hmm,  lemme try it

Answer (score 0):

You can't "focus" an image unless you have an interactive element or navigate to it using tab. Try adding an interactive element on a wrapper div like so:

```
<a href="#" onBlur={this.showToolTip} onClick={this.copyToClipboard}>
  <img ref={this.copyRef} data-tip data-for="clip" src={require( "../../assets/img/copy.svg")} alt={ ""} className="copy_link_image"  />
</a>
```

You can also focus an  - with the help of tabindex so:

```
<img ref={this.copyRef} data-tip data-for="clip" src={require( "../../assets/img/copy.svg")} alt={ ""} className="copy_link_image" onBlur={this.showToolTip} onClick={this.copyToClipboard} tabindex="0" />
```